# lm models over all possible pairwise combinations of the columns of two matrices

Tags: r, loops, matrix, apply, lm

I am working through a problem at the moment in R and have got stuck. I have searched around on various help lists for assistance but could not find anything - but apologies if I have missed something. A dummy example of my problem is below. I will continue to work on it, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your time.

I have a matrix of response variables:

```
p<-matrix(c(rnorm(120,1),
    rnorm(120,1),
    rnorm(120,1)),
    120,3)
```

and two matrices of covariates:

```
g<-matrix(c(rep(1:3, each=40),
    rep(3:1, each=40),
    rep(1:3, 40)),
    120,3)

m<-matrix(c(rep(1:2, 60),
    rep(2:1, 60),
    rep(1:2, each=60)),
    120,3)
```

For all combinations of the columns of the covariate matrices g and m I want to run these two models:

```
test <- function(uniq_m, uniq_g, p = p) {   
    full <- lm(p ~ factor(uniq_m) * factor(uniq_g))
        null <- lm(p ~ factor(uniq_m) + factor(uniq_g))
        return(list('f'=full, 'n'=null))
}
```

So I want to test for an interaction between column 1 of m and column 1 of g, then column 2 of m and column 1 of g, then column 2 of m and column 2 of g...and so forth across all possible pairwise interactions. The response variable is the same each time and is a matrix containing multiple columns.

So far, I can do this for a single combination of columns:

```
test_1 <- test(m[ ,1], g[ ,1], p)
```

And I can also run the model over all columns of m and one coloumn of g:

```
test_2 <- apply(m, 2, function(uniq_m) {
    test(uniq_m, g[ ,1], p = p)
})
```

I can then get the F statistics for each response variable of each model:

```
sapply(summary(test_2[[1]]$f), function(x) x$fstatistic)
sapply(summary(test_2[[1]]$n), function(x) x$fstatistic)
```

And I can compare models for each response variable using an F-test:

```
d1<-colSums(matrix(residuals(test_2[[1]]$n),nrow(g),ncol(p))^2)
d2<-colSums(matrix(residuals(test_2[[2]]$f),nrow(g),ncol(p))^2)
F<-((d1-d2) / (d2/114))
```

My question is how do I run the lm models over all combinations of columns from the m and the g matrix, and get the F-statistics?

While this is a dummy example, the real analysis will have a response matrix that is 700 x 8000, and the covariate matrices will be 700 x 4000 and 700 x 100 so I need something that is as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps, this is some code a friend of mine shared with me. It may not be exactly what you need but might set you off in the right direction (though given this is 9 months later than you asked it, it may be of no use to you specifically!):

```
#### this first function models the correlation and fixes the text size based on the strength of the correlation
panel.cor <- function(x, y, digits = 2, prefix = "", cex.cor, ...)
{
  usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
  par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
  r <- abs(cor(x, y))
  txt <- format(c(r, 0.123456789), digits = digits)[1]
  txt <- paste0(prefix, txt)
  if(missing(cex.cor)) cex.cor <- 0.8/strwidth(txt)
  text(0.5, 0.5, txt, cex = cex.cor * r)
}

##### this function places a histogram of your data on the diagonal
panel.hist <- function(x, ...)
{
  usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
  par(usr = c(usr[1:2], 0, 1.5) )
  h <- hist(x, plot = FALSE)
  breaks <- h$breaks; nB <- length(breaks)
  y <- h$counts; y <- y/max(y)
  rect(breaks[-nB], 0, breaks[-1], y, col="cyan", ...)
}

### read in Fishers famous iris dataset for our example
data(iris)
head(iris)

library(corrgram)
##corrgram also gives you some nice panel options to use in pairs, but you dont necesarily need them
##e.g. panel.ellipse, panel.pie, panel.conf
library(asbio)
##asbio offers more panel options, such as a linear regression (panel.lm) etc

### run pairs() on your data
### set upper panel to panel.cor (the function we just wrote), and diagonal to panel.hist
### do what you like for the lower, add a smoother line isnt very informative
pairs(~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length,  data=iris, lower.panel=panel.lm, upper.panel=panel.cor, diag.panel = panel.hist, main="pair plots of variables")
```

All credit to James Keating.